# Display expression and result of calculation in MuPad

Tags: matlab, mupad

Imagine I define two variables within a MuPad Notebook:

```
x:=2;
y:=5
```

For the product

```
z=x*y
```

I get displayed:

[image]

And if I use `hold`, I can get the expression:

```
z=hold(x*y)
```

[image]

But now I'd like to have both, the expression displayed and the result. The two options which appeared logical to me, do not worK:

```
z=hold(x*y);z
```

and

```
z=hold(x*y);eval(z);
```

[image]

**How can I get displayed the expression AND the result?**
If in two lines it would be alright, but I'd prefer in one line like:

**z = x y = 10**

Comment: What about `val(z)` ?

Comment: It does not seems to make a difference to `eval(z)`...

Comment: The problem is that you don't assign `x*y` to `z` in the code above because you left out the colon `:`. You can use `z:=hold(x*y);z`.

Comment: @Matt thats the code I already tried?

Comment: In your code, the colon is missing. You have `z=` instead of `z:=`. Therefore you never assign something to `z`. Since `z` is undefined it will be always `z` without a value.

Comment: @Matt I understand, I finally got the difference between `:=` and `=` - do you see a possibilty to get the desired output? Some tweak or macro?

Comment: I tried a bit, but couldn't find a convincing solution now. You can try using a combination with [`print`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/print.html), [`expr2text`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/expr2text.html), `hold` and `_concat`. When you have the expected behaviour, there is the possibility to write a procedure. In the documentation for `expr2text` is an example.

Comment: @Matt I also fiddled around a little, seems it's not possible to get everything as convenient as in MathCad. However If you'd write an answer explaining the differences between `:=` and `=` and that this was the problem, I'll accept it. If you don't want to, let me know and I'll do to get this thing solved.

Comment: Thanks, I'll write this answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried some combinations with `print`, `expr2text`, `hold` and `_concat` but couldn't find a convincing solution to get the desired result. But there is an explanation why the second line just returns `z` and not `10`.

#### Assignment vs. Equation

`z` is the result in the second line because you didn't assign something to `z` yet. So the result says that `z` is `z`. In MuPad `=` is part of an expression. The assignment operator is `:=` and therefore not the same as in Matlab. The only difference between them is the colon.

**Writing an equation**

For writing an equation, we use `=` as part of the expression. There is an equivalent function: `_equal`. So the following two lines generate the same result:

```
x+y = 2
_equal(x+y, 2)
```

[image: result1]

**Assign `value` to `x`**

For an assignment we use `:=` (in Matlab this would be only `=`). There is an equivalent function: `_assign`. So again, the following two lines generate the same result:

```
x := value
_assign(x, value)
```

[image: result2]

**Assign the equation `x+y = 2` to `eqn`**

Here we can clearly see the difference:

```
eqn := x+y = 2
_assign(eqn, _equal(x+y, 2))
```

[image: result3]